# Wordpress search page redirect to custom page

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to redirect WordPress default search page (`search.php`) to `/videos/search_string/`

If has pagination content then the URL I want to like this `/videos/search_string/page_no`

The default search URL is like `?s=search_string`

I have used the below code for testing but its not working correctly and also tried many more. What I'll do now to solve my problem? I am using WordPress version 4.6

```
add_rewrite_rule( 'videos/([^/]+)/?$', 'index.php?s=$matches[1]', 'top' );
add_rewrite_rule( 'videos/([^/]+)(/videos/(\d+))/?$', 'index.php?s=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[3]', 'top' );

// redirect immediately
if ( isset( $_GET[ 's' ] ) ) {
    $location = '/videos/' . $_GET[ 's' ];
    if ( isset( $_GET[ 'paged' ] ) && $_GET[ 'paged' ] )
        $location .= '/videos/' . $_GET[ 'paged' ];
        wp_redirect( trailingslashit( home_url( $location ) ), 301 );
        exit;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a rewrite rule to `.htaccess` on a apache Webserver using those regexes you already have:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^videos/([^/]+)/$ index.php?s=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^videos/([^/]+)/([0-9]+)/$ index.php?s=$1&paged=$2 [L]
```

...or use your PHP code -- both are ok if you write them precisely:

```
if ( isset( $_GET[ 's' ] ) && strlen( $_GET[ 's' ] ) ) {
    $location = '/videos/' . urlencode( $_GET[ 's' ] );
    if ( isset( $_GET[ 'paged' ] ) && $_GET[ 'paged' ] ) {
        $location .= '/' . $_GET[ 'paged' ];
    }
    wp_redirect( trailingslashit( home_url( $location ) ), 301 );
    exit;
}
```

Comment: I don't know what to add in `.htaccess` please give me the code for   `.htaccess`